# How to delete a database record by unchecking a checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php

$sql = "select * from tb_transport";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$a=1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $sql_2="select * from transport_two where transport_id='$row[name]'";
    $query_2=mysql_query($sql_2);
    $row_2=mysql_fetch_array($query_2);
?>

    <input type="checkbox"  name="courses[<?php echo $a; ?>][crs]" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" <?php  if($row_2["transport_id"]=="$row[name]") { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /><    ?php echo $row["name"]; ?>

<?php  
    $a=$a+1;  
}
?>

    <input type="submit" name="save" />
</form>
```

Here is my form and I'm having a number of checkboxes dependent on my database records.

Here, also I have applied code that if a checkbox value exists in database then it is shown checked.

If I have checked a checkbox, then a row gets inserted with the checkbox value.

Now what I am looking for is that if I uncheck the checked checbox then that database row gets deleted.

How can I do this?

Here is my insertion code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["save"])) {
    $arr = $_POST["courses"];

    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
        if (!empty($arr[$i]['crs'])) {
            $a = $arr[$i]['crs'];
            mysql_query("insert into transport_two set transport_id='$a'");
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using mysqli ?

Comment: no reason..just like that...can you please suggest me foy my problem??

Comment: This `$sql_2="select * from transport_two where transport_id='$row[name]'";` does not work. Is `name` a `constant`? You have to use: `$sql_2="select * from transport_two where transport_id='" . $row['name'] . "'";` See [this short article](http://blog.flowl.info/2014/cant-put-array-variables-right-string/) for an explanation and why this is critical especially in associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete from a database at the moment when a checkbox is marked/unmarked, you need to use JavaScript or jQuery.

If you want to delete from a database at the moment a user clicks on the submit button, you have to send the value to your php - script which updates/deletes from a database.

Comment: so can you tell me how to do it

Comment: you want to delete it at the moment when the checkbox is clicked right - which means you have to use jQuery. Do you have any experience on this?

Answer (score 0):

just give a simple class to checkbox.

```
<form action="" method="post">

        <?php
     $sql="select * from tb_transport";
  $query=mysql_query($sql);
       $a=1;
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
     $sql_2="select * from transport_two where transport_id='$row[name]'";
  $query_2=mysql_query($sql_2);
  $row_2=mysql_fetch_array($query_2);
       ?>
    <input type="checkbox" class="deleteFromDb"  name="courses[<?php echo $a; ?>][crs]" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" <?php  if($row_2["transport_id"]=="$row[name]") { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> /><?php echo $row["name"]; ?>

       <?php    
      $a=$a+1;  
   }
             ?>

  <input type="submit" name="save" />
     </form>
```

Here click on any check box and jquery check it is check or uncheck. if it uncheck then ajax send request to delete this record from db.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $(".deleteFromDb").change(function(e){
              if ($(this).prop('checked')==false){ 

            $.ajax({type: "POST",
                    url: "deleterecord.php",
                    data: { id:$(this).val().trim() },
                    success:function(result){
                      var response = JSON.parse(result);
                       if(response.error){
                             //here provide a error msg to user.
                             alert(response.error);
                        }
                      if(response.success){
                            alert("record deleted");
                       }

            }});
          });
        }
        });
```

Delete.php
Here perform your delete action.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$strSQL = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE id = ".$id);
if($strSQL){
  $result['success'] = "success";
}
else
        {
          $result['error'] = "try again";
        }

echo json_encode($result); die;
```

Now when you click any checkbox and if it ubcheck, the record will delete from db.

Comment: error at the end somewhere here     }

            }});
          });
        }
        });

Comment: if(response.success){
                            alert("record deleted");
                       }

            }});
              }
          });

        
        });

Find this section and replace

Comment: You provide name in the value part of checkbox. Here give id and then delete.

Comment: i gave id but still nothing is get deleted moreover the page is not getting reloaded after clicking on submit button

Comment: the problem that i feel here here is the the post value that we are fetching at the delete page